# issues with jquery and canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Here is my code:

```
$('#add_shape').click(function() {
                            var rectHeight = $('#rect_height_input').val();
                            var WidthOrRadius = $('#widthorradius').val();

                            $('<canvas>').attr({
                                id:'canvas'                             
                            }).css({
                                height:function() {
                                    if (rectHeight > 0) {
                                        return rectHeight + 'px';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        return WidthOrRadius + 'px';
                                    }
                                },
                                width:WidthOrRadius + 'px'
                            })
                            .appendTo('#work_area');
                                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');                              

                                ctx.fillStyle = $('#color_list option:selected').val();
                                ctx.fillRect(0, 0 , WidthOrRadius, rectHeight);

});
```

This code works on jsfiddle (here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/xwg5f/) but not on my browser. i have no idea whats wrong. can someone help please?

Comment: @czarchaic--firefox latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give correct result, if you have written code in HTML5.

Are you sure you are coding in HTML5?

Comment: @Robin_Michael_Poothurai--I'm pretty sure i am. there are no additional plugins needed to code in html5 right? Just a doctype?

Comment: @codeninja, Yes. you are right HTML5 no need any additional plugins but all browsers wont support HTML5 only latest versions in that also some tags wont work.